# In what situation does eventloop.inEventLoop() == false?

Tags: java, netty, nio, channel

I am reading netty 4 source code. `eventLoop.inEventLoop()` appears everywhere.
According to Netty in Action:

> A Channel is registered for its lifetime with a single EventLoop.
>   A single EventLoop may be assigned to one or more Channels.
>   a channel has and only has one eventLoop/thread.

Theoretically, `eventLoop.inEventLoop()` is to make sure code blocks are executed by the assigned eventLoop/thread. Furthermore, if you call something from non-io thread, `eventLoop.inEventLoop()` goes to false, and will be executed by assigned eventLoop/thread.

For example, the following code goes to else block(`NioSocketChannel$NioSocketChannelUnsafe(AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe).register(EventLoop, ChannelPromise)`) where the channel is not registered(assigned to an eventloop/thread).

```
if (eventLoop.inEventLoop()) {
    register0(promise);
} else {
    try {
        eventLoop.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                register0(promise);
            }
        });
    } catch (Throwable t) {
...
    }
}
```

I am really confused, whats the point of `eventLoop.inEventLoop()`. 
What does `eventLoop.inEventLoop()` protect from?

Besides the above one, can you give me some more specific examples in practice to demonstrate why and how `eventloop.inEventLoop() == false`? What kind of code do you call? Where do you call? How does the code make `eventloop.inEventLoop() == false`?

Answer (score 0):

This kind of code ensures that only the correct eventLoop/thread works with/change the `Channel` object. This solves a lot of race conditions and multi threading problems when only one specific thread can work with the `Channel` object. This has something to do with what is called "thread safe" and if or if not a class is considered "thread safe" or not. The code can be read as follow:

```
if (amIOnTheCorrectThread()) {
    doTheActualWork(); // I do the work
} else {
   scheduleOnTheCorrectThread.performAction({ doTheActualWork(); }); // let him do the work
}
```

Depending on if you are on the correct thread, the work is done directly (on the correct thread) or the task is off-loaded to the correct thread, so that the other thread does the work. The other thread does that by having an endless loop and check if there are any new tasks to execute. As an example, check the `run()` method of the [`io.netty.channel.ThreadPerChannelEventLoop`](https://github.com/taojiaenx/netty-source-study/blob/ab4fa760ae6130a926290504371b95a625ddb019/transport/src/main/java/io/netty/channel/ThreadPerChannelEventLoop.java) class:

> ```
> @Override
> protected void run() {
>     for (;;) {
>         Runnable task = takeTask();
>         if (task != null) {
>             task.run();
>             // [...]
>         }
>     [...]
> ```

Comment: I am working on a module building on netty. It starts a eventloop to accept incoming messages. It seems that inEventLoop() always goes true. Am I supposed to call those methods which contain inEventLoop() from outside of eventloop? If so, why and where?

Comment: @MalPsycho If the methods are `public` they can be called from other classes and maybe from different threads. This check ensures that the action is performed on the correct thread.

Comment: I understand this. I just have never met a situatuion that I have to call those methods outside of eventloop. Can you give a real life example? Don’t have to be code, just a simple idea may really helpful.

Comment: @MalPsycho Some other class can have a reference to your `Channel` object and this other class is using a thread to do something else. At some point that thread might call a method on the `Channel` object. To avoid race conditions and threading problems this guard is put in place to ensure only the thread responsible for the eventLoop is allowed to perform the requested action.